# Incompatible types in assignment for mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm adding 60 minutes in a `datetime` object. For this I'm using `timedelta`, the add works well but mypy throws me the following error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "datetime", variable has type "int")  [assignment]
```

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class TokenExp:
  LIFETIME = 60

  def __init__(self,  lifetime_in_minutes: int = LIFETIME) -> None:
   
     self.lifetime = timedelta(minutes=lifetime_in_minutes)
     self.token_exp = 0
   
  def token_expiration(self):
      now = datetime.utcnow()
      self.token_exp = now + self.lifetime
      return self.token_exp
```

Is there anything I can do to mypy accept my solution?

Comment: Are you sure this piece of code is enough to see the error?

Comment: Somewhere in your actual code, `token_exp` has been explicitly hinted or previously inferred to be an `int`. This code does not produce that error.

Comment: Note that static typing prevents dynamic programming idioms like `x = 3; x = str(x)`.   You can change the value of `x` at runtime, but statically speaking you can't change the *type* of `x` while doing so.

Comment: @chepner even if I remove the int type from _init_ I still get the same mypy error

Comment: `0` has type `int`, so the type of `self.token_exp` is inferred to be `int`. You can't change its type whenever you like. `token_exp` should perhaps have type `Optional[datetime]`, initialized to `None`, or given a default value far, far in the future.

Comment: Or, `token_exp` should be a *property* whose value is computed from `self.lifetime` and `now` on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

Following @chepner suggestion I create a include a property and mypy doesn't complained

Here is the code snippet

```
    @property
    def token_exp(self) -> datetime:
        return datetime.utcnow() + self.lifetime
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Optional

class TokenExp:
    LIFETIME: int = 60
    
    def __init__(self, lifetime_in_minutes: int = LIFETIME) -> None:
        self.lifetime: timedelta = timedelta(minutes=lifetime_in_minutes)
        self.token_exp: Optional[datetime] = None
    
    def token_expiration(self) -> datetime:
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        self.token_exp = now + self.lifetime
        return self.token_exp
```